# GitHub Actions: How would you delete failed github workflow run(s) with powershell?

Tags: powershell, rest

### Problem:

- Pull Requests that fail will increase the list of failed runs. This list can get difficult to manage, the user interface will only let you delete 1 failed run at a time.
- `https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}/actions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the script that has helped me out by using the [github api documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/checks#create-a-check-run).

```
$token = 'asdlf234lk23jkl2j65tl1234lkj_PAT'
$owner = 'bob'
$repo = 'coolToolRepoName'

$body = [PSCustomObject]@{
  status = 'failure'
  per_page = 10
} | ConvertTo-Hashtable


$header = [PSCustomObject]@{
  Authorization = "token $token"
} | ConvertTo-Hashtable

$failures = Invoke-RestMethod https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/actions/runs -Headers $header -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json'

foreach($rec in $failures.workflow_runs){
    Write-Host deleting $rec.id
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method delete -Uri "https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/actions/runs/$($rec.id)" -Headers $header
}
```